# Assign resources concurrently in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, concurrency, deadlock

I'm trying to implement a marketplace to sell certain fungible items and I want these items to be assigned pseudo randomly to each user.
Let's say I have a collection of item `items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

A user can make a request to buy a certain amount of items. `POST /buy?count=N`

In my code, I get a sample of the items and I want to sell these to the user `[1, 3, 4] = sample(items)`

What I'm currently doing is the following

- Create a db transaction
- Get a sample from the remaining items to sell to the user (fail if none are available)
- Assign the sample to the user by creating an entry `(user_id, item_id)` per item in a table `user_items` (if I cannot assign the current sample, try again with a new sample)
- Debit the user balance for the purchase (rollback the transaction if they cannot afford it)
- Commit the transaction

I'm basically using the database (mysql) to guarantee the consistency for the operations. The problem is that when I stress test this logic the queries fail with a `ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK` or `ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT`.

A couple of things I tried:

I tried sorting the items in the sample thinking it would prevent deadlocks but it didn't work.

I was thinking of putting all these operations into a queue and then processing it one by one, but the application is running on a cluster on aws, so there are multiple instances.

I thought that setting the database isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE` would decrease the performances but DEFINITIVELY solve the problem but it didn't.

I think using the database to guarantee the consistency is the way to go but I don't know how.

Here a simple log of 4 clients <s>, I understand why client 2, 3, 4 cannot get a lock on the resources (5 and 8 are locked by client 1) but</s> why deadlock? Why they cannot just fail?

```
C1 AVAILABLE 9 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] PURCHASING 3 [ 1, 5, 8 ]

C2 AVAILABLE 9 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] PURCHASING 3 [ 5, 7, 9 ]

C3 AVAILABLE 9 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] PURCHASING 3 [ 4, 5, 9 ]

C4 AVAILABLE 9 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] PURCHASING 3 [ 2, 4, 8 ]

C2 FAILED for 3 [ 5, 7, 9 ] ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: insert into `user_items` (`item_id`, `user_id`) values (5, 6) - ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

C4 FAILED for 3 [ 2, 4, 8 ] ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: insert into `user_items` (`item_id`, `user_id`) values (2, 6) - ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

C3 FAILED for 3 [ 4, 5, 9 ] ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: insert into `user_items` (`item_id`, `user_id`) values (4, 6) - ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

C1 ASSIGNED SUCCESSFULLY 3 [ 1, 5, 8 ]
```

Comment: I was faced with a similar challenge but addressed it with a different approach. I created a lambda microservice leveraging `PubSub` to manage the queuing, processing, and results response of multiple concurrent requests similar to your scenario. I'm interested to see what solutions others provide and learn from them. But, if you don't get an answer that works by relying on the DB to guarantee consistency I'd be happy to share details on the approach I implemented.

Comment: @dusthaines did you use the lambda for queuing or did you use a dedicated aws queue? If you can share more details I would really appreciated it

Comment: I used Lambda to run a serverless Node microservice (so I didn't have to run and maintain an additional EB application server). It acted as an intermediary between the DB and a collection of load balanced application servers. By leveraging Redis Pub/Sub to execute queries asynchronously even if they were made at the same time.The Pub/Sub microservice would receive and queue the queries, execute them in turn, then broadcast results back in turn. It's a more complicated architecture but had some additional benefits beyond query consistency in my specific use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with gap locks, the table in which I was performing the inserts has unique indices on both columns. To prevent duplicates and in general to maintain the index updated, the db engine lock entire regions spanning several values.

What was happening is that concurrent queries were locking different regions on top of each other resulting in deadlocks.

I changed the logic by using updates to get the row lock on the items, if the updates were successful I could go on with the inserts otherwise I was just aborting the transaction.

In this way I either had one query running at any given time (if the partitioning resulted in certain values assigned to the different queries, only one would continue) or multiple query on disjoint set of data.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, very interesting combinations of events and configurations that contributed to the behavior.